junit reporter writes only last test suite to xml
I have cypress unit and end to end tests in my project. I am writing github actions workflow which will do testing, unit test and end to end testing using cypress commands. I want test results in the xml format but junit reporter is writing only last test suite to xml report in github actions
I have written this code in my workflow
  - name: Generate Hash
    id: generate-hash
    run: |
      HASH=$(echo -n "$(date)" | sha256sum | cut -c1-8)
      echo "HASH_VALUE=$HASH" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  - name: Run End-to-end test
    id: e2e-test
    run: |
      npx nx run ${{ inputs.repo_project_name }}:e2e --reporter junit --reporter-options "mochaFile=${{ github.workspace }}/apps/${{ inputs.repo_project_name }}/cypress/e2e-results/${{ steps.generate-hash.outputs.HASH_VALUE }}result.xml"

I expected to get the entire test results into single xml report but what I am getting is last test suite in the xml report. I have taken this command from cypress documentation.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters#Merging-reports-across-spec-files
-> Have you tried using the [hash] strategy outlined in this document?

@agoff I have used it. ${{ steps.generate-hash.outputs.HASH_VALUE }} This gives us hash value

@agoff Yep I got it. I was figuring out about [hash]. Initially I thought that we have to provide the hash value. But I got it that [hash] is generated by cypress. Thanks for your help.

The documentation lacks explicit mention of the [hash] placeholder. Initially, I utilized a unique identifier such as the GitHub SHA (commit hash). However, upon further investigation, I discovered that Cypress generates its own unique identifier, designated as [hash], which should be incorporated into the command for optimal functionality.
The final command looks like this:
npx nx run ${{ inputs.repo_project_name }}:e2e --reporter junit --reporter-options "mochaFile=${{ github.workspace }}/apps/${{ inputs.repo_project_name }}/cypress/e2e-results/e2e-result-[hash].xml
